# Sort string array with numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this array, which I want to sort:

```
['reactor-sum', 'reactor-sum-23', 'reactor-sum-15', '99', 'reform-match-5', 'reform-match', 'docker-rev']
```

I want to have it sorted in a way that I have:
1) numbers first
2) sorted alphabetically and if there are numbers in the end of the string - put first the strings without numbers and then the ones with numbers sorted numerically.

Expected result array:

```
['99',
'docker-rev',
'reactor-sum',
'reactor-sum-15'
'reactor-sum-23', 
'reform-match',
'reform-match-5']
```

So far I tried things like:

```
             const sortAlphaNum = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true });
             searchResults.sort(sortAlphaNum);
```

and the regular .sort(), but I can't quite figure out how to achieve what I want.

Anybody have some ideas on how to best sort this array? My biggest issue is with putting the non number strings in front of the ones with numbers like: 
[example, example1]

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: Its the second array. This is how I expect it to result.

Comment: Your code can return the expected result array.

Answer (score -2):

Normal `sort()` should work out of the box. See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seLdx2qp/)